# Safety / security of editable files on server

Tags: javascript, database, security, server, storage

Sorry if this is a stupid question googling didn't bring up much or not as specific as what I'd like to know.

My question essentially boils down to this:

How do services allow users to write their own code / edit it and serve it securely without the worry of it being malicious affecting the server it's being stored on.

An example of this is editing javascript and other web files on many platforms to customize your design.

What's the storage schema here?

Comment: I don't think storage is the problem here: it's safe to store code, as long as it doesn't contain SQL injections (which are automatically escaped, with a proper ORM). The real problem is the execution of user-submitted server side code: the only solution I see is running it with very limited I/O and network access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On sites like that, the JavaScript is saved to the server, but it is not executed there. To the server, the JavaScript is simply a text file that it serves to you. The JavaScript files are downloaded to your browser and executed on your device, so any JavaScript that you write to change your own experience only affects you.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. That's kinda what I thought, but then I was still fuzzy on the execution / download process when the client is talking to the server despite knowing JavaScript is executed on the front end. My use case / thought expirement here was how sites such as WordPress etc allow people to edit web dev files and how that's sae.

Comment: Assuming you are referring to hosted WordPress (not WordPress you host on your own servers), in that case or in the case of pretty much any web hosting service your code is run on virtual machines in their data center, so if you upload malicious code to your server, the code only affects your site's instance since virtual machines are isolated from each other and the host server that they are run on.